# Boost::Python: safely store a Python callable and its arguments to call it later

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I want to create Python bindings for a C++ component **invoker** which takes a 
function object and calls it *later* from another thread. 
Usage in C++ looks like this:

```
invoker my_invoker(thread_holding_context);

// this will queue ome_class::some_method() to be executed later in another
// thread and it returns immediately
my_invoker.invoke(std::bind(&some_class::some_method, this));
```

Of course you can use pure Python code for this rather than wrapping a C++ 
component, but this `invoker` is part of a framework which is used in a greater
context and I *have* to use it.

In Boost::Python a wrapper could look like this:

```
struct invoker_wrap 
    : public invoker, public wrapper<invoker> {
    explicit invoker_wrap(thread_holding_context) {...}

    void wrap_invoke(boost::python::object callable) {
        // queue the callable - don't execute it yet
        invoker::invoke(std::bind(&invoker_wrap::call, this, callable));
    }

    void call(boost::python::object callable) {
        std::cout << "call: " << callable.ptr() << std::endl;
        PyGILState_STATE gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();  // seems to be not needed
        callable();
        PyGILState_Release(gstate);                     // seems to be not needed
    }
};

class_<invoker_wrap, boost::noncopyable>("invoker", init<thread_holding_context &>())
    .def("invoke", &invoker_wrap::wrap_invoke);
```

The Python code looks similar to this:

```
_invoker = invoker(thread_holding_context)

def my_func():
    print("%.1f %s: my_func()" % (time.time(), threading.currentThread().getName()))

def thread_func():
    while True:
        _invoker.invoke(my_func)
        time.sleep(1)

threading.Thread(target=thread_func).start()
```

This code somehow works - but it behaves strangely. `invoker::call` is being
called correctly but the but the output of the callable itself is executed 
**much later** (up to 57 secs to be precise).

I have two questions now:

- since the `invoker` doesn't run the callable immediately but stores it
  a queue, `invoke()` returns before the call and Python should clean up 
  all data needed for the call. Doesn't it? 
  Should I **copy** or **protect** the callable and *all it's arguments*?
  How can this be done?
- Why is the output from the Python code printed later while the C++ 
  output isn't? Since the C++ code and the Python code run in the same 
  process they share `stdout`. I can solve this  by calling 
  `sys.stdout.flush()` in the callback but I don't understand why.